# KStream-Kstream join based on IDs

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to do join based on value columns in kstream but not sure how?

Currenly, I am able to do join based on key in my local kafka like this

```
 def kStreamToKStreamJoin(inputTopic1: String,
                          inputTopic2: String,
                          outputTopicName: String,
                          storeName: String): Topology = {

val builder: StreamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder

val userRegions: KStream[String, String] = builder.stream(inputTopic1)
val regionMetrics: KStream[String, Long] = builder.stream(inputTopic2)

regionMetrics.join(userRegions)(
  ((regionValue, metricValue) => regionValue + "/" + metricValue),
  JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(5L))
).to(outputTopicName)

val outputTopic: KTable[String, String] =
  builder.table(
    outputTopicName,
    Materialized.as(storeName)
  )

builder.build()
```

But I want to do join based on certain columns like we do generally in Sqls(eg based on some ID keys).

Comment: _join based on certain columns_ - 1) Not proper to think in terms of "columns" 2) AFAIK, you cannot join on value's fields, only record keys. Therefore you need to `map` the streams to a common key before joining

Comment: You might also want  not fully setting common key, with foreign key join as well https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/foreign-key-joins/kstreams.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer Okay so I am trying to use selectKey to create map. 
Lets suppose we have something like this:
 topic1-> id,name,address
 topic2->id,contact 
So todo inner join based on id's if I try: 

`val topic1: KStream[String, String] = builder.stream(inputTopic1)
 val topic2: KStream[String, String] = builder.stream(inputTopic2)
 topic1.selectKey((k,v)=>v).join(topic2.selectKey((k,v)=>v))(
 ((topic1Value, topic2Value) => topic1Value + "/" + topic2Value), JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(5L))
 ).to(outputTopicName)`
 But am not able to see any records in the output topic?

Comment: Why `topic2.selectKey((k,v)=>v)`? Are you following any tutorials? Perhaps it would help if you got a copy of "Kafka Streams in Action" book